# Animate Bootstrap progressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some trouble using the animation with jquery on the progress bar. I retrieve some percentage from the database and put it as text inside the progress bar div, but I can't find a way to change the base width in the animated properties. Is it possible to change the color of the progress according to the current value of the progress bar (i.e. : < 33% -> red, < 66% -> yellow, else green)?

```js
console.log($(".progress-bar").text())

$(".progress-bar").animate({
  width: $(this).text() //I want to get the value inside the progressbar div but doesn't seems like to work
}, {
  duration: 2000,
  step: function(now, fx) {}
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 progress-container">
  <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <!-- Part retrieved from the database -->
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%">60%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WEYKL/968/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake with context. `this` in options refers to window object, not `$(".progress-bar")`

```js
$( ".progress-bar" ).animate({
   width: $( ".progress-bar" ).text()
}, {
   duration: 2000,
   step: function( now, fx ) {
         $(this).removeClass (function (index, css) {
      return (css.match (/(^|\s)progress-bar-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
      });
         if (now < 33) {
         $(this).addClass('progress-bar-danger');
      } else if (now < 66) {
      $(this).addClass('progress-bar-warning');
      } else {
      $(this).addClass('progress-bar-success');
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 progress-container">
  <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <!-- Part retrieved from the database -->
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%">60%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is your working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/WEYKL/970/)

Comment: mark this as the right answer if it solves your issue, please:)

Comment: done, I edited your jsfiddle you gave me so it handle the color, http://jsfiddle.net/WEYKL/972/ , can you edit your answer so people who are looking for run-time color can see it ?